# Highstock: exporting buttons

Tags: highcharts

I have followed the simple step of adding exporting in my Highstock object:

```
        exporting: {
            enabled: true
        }
```

and it is not displaying any button.

I have also included this at the beginning of the page:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.2.4/modules/exporting.js" rel="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there anything  else I need to do ?
Thank you

Update:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/1.2.5/modules/exporting.js" rel="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/1.2.5/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Any example on Js fiddle would be more helpful.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it exactly because it's created dynamically and has a lot of data. :-s

Comment: Without source code, we have no ability to check your syntax. In header you need to have: 

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

Comment: I have updated the post with my imports....

Comment: You should include highstock.js before exporting.js